# "No provider for AlertController!" npm ionic-angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

The following code is for the custom splash screen component in ionic app where I have requested to server for token and identity! Using "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2"

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BackendService} from "../../services/backend.service";
import {SessionService} from "../../services/session.service";
import {AlertController} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-splash-screen',
    templateUrl: './splash-screen.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./splash-screen.component.scss']
})

export class SplashScreenComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private backendService: BackendService,
            private sessionService: SessionService, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

ngOnInit() {

    if (this.sessionService.getBearerToken()) {
        this.requestForIdentity();
    } else {
        this.backendService.Token().subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.sessionService.addAccessToken(response.access_token);
            this.sessionService.addRefreshToken(response.refresh_token);
            this.requestForIdentity();
        }, error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
}

requestForIdentity() {
    this.backendService.GetIdentity().subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.showAlert();
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

showAlert() {
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Friend!',
        subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
}

}
```

now, when the identity response received, wanted to show a simple alert! but as per the API documentation, I injected AlertController in the SplashScreenComponent and on build, the following error occurred! couldn't come up with any solution searching around the internet.

[AlertController Error! No provider for AlertController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRG9M.png)

The SplashScreenComponent is inside SplashScreen module which is a lazy loaded module.

Comment: is AlertController is angular service

Comment: @NinjaJami No! I found the example here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert, it's a ionic UI Component

Comment: I think AlerController is a service from Ionic. Can u specify it in providers also and try?

Comment: @NinjaJami Tried, but no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my requirement I was using 'ionic-angular's AlertController, @NinjaJami's Answer helped me to dug into the problem more specifically!

Stopped using 'ionic-angular' and replaced,

```
import {AlertController} from "ionic-angular";
```

with,

```
import {AlertController} from "@ionic/angular";
```

and, replaced,

```
showAlert() {
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Friend!',
        subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

with:

```
showAlert() {
    const alert: any = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Friend!',
        subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
        buttons: ['OK']
    });

    alert.then((_alert: any)=> {
        _alert.present();
    })
}
```

**explanation:** this.alertCtrl.create() return a Promise, so, couldn't call directly alert.present(), so, using alert.then() was able to call the present() function.

Special Thanks to @NinjaJami

Comment: Thank you! Helped using import {AlertController} from "@ionic/angular"; and async presentAlert from here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert. You saved  my day!

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have imported **IonicModule**

```
 imports:      [ IonicModule.forRoot(),BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
```

Working Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-error?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I was already using IonicModule.forRoot(), but was not able to get a working solution with ionic-angular. Finally after some tweaks, able to make it working! I will share my solution as an answer.